# Are robes considered light armor?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Will my light armor skills go up wearing robes? I don't see the "light armor" tag on them. I have been wearing robes my whole game and have very low armor skills in every tree.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No; robes are clothing and are not considered to be armor, light or heavy. As such, robes will not increase your light armor skill.

Answer (score 8):

Robes and other apparel which do not have the armor tags - are not armor.  As a consequence, these items:

- do not grant armor skill experience
- do not benefit from armor perks or skill
- do not grant [hidden armor rating](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/52776/9192)

You can still get some of these benefits while wearing robes if you wear some armor in other slots (head, feet, hands, shield)

Comment: Note: If you have points in Mage Armor in the Alteration tree, equipping armor in your other slots will render the talent points worthless.

Comment: To be fair, Mage Armor was worthless from the start.

Comment: @kotekzot LOL so true... so true

Comment: The Mage Armor spell would be ok if it granted full hidden armor rating.  It does not, and so it is lame.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't level up light armor, the only the perk it helps (destruction, conjuration) and if that's not enough when you equip robes and hoods you still have room for gauntlets and boots. **So no**.