# How to level up armor skills in legendary difficulty?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've started a new Skyrim run a few days ago, and since I was looking for a harder challenge, I've set the difficulty to the highest setting, *legendary*. I'm leveling *conjuration*, *two-handed* and *heavy armor* - at least that's what I'm trying to. The problem with the latter is that most enemies can one-hit kill me (I thought this would stop after a few levels, but I'm at level 18 now, still no change), so I have to hide behind my follower (Lydia FTW) and summoned creature. That works fine for killing enemies, but since I'm barely hit at all, my armor skill doesn't level up. What can I do about this? Is there a good way to level my armor skill? (please no suggestions that involve lowering the difficulty) The only things that don't kill me in one to two hits are like mudcrabs, and even those come dangerously close ...

Comment: How much armor and hit points do you have? By level 18 you should be pretty close to the 80% cap (if you haven't hit it already), and be at least 200+ hit points. That should definitely take more than 2 hits even with only basic healing spells/potions. If all else fails you can always try the skill trainers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a level 14 character with 200 displayed armor rating and 200 health, a mudcrab hit on ledgendary does ~15% of my health (I guess 20-30 hp).

Your problem is probably that your armor rating is too low. Wear armor (not clothes) on all four body slots (head, chest, hands, legs) to get the extra 100 hidden armor bonus. Upgrade all your armor at the blacksmith to increase your armor and spend perk points on your armor skills.

Check out the armor -> mitigation [calculation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/36569/9192).  Here's how perks [influence](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/38744/9192) your armor.

---

The basics of leveling armor skill are: get hit, don't block and don't die.  If you block, you get block skill instead of armor skill. If mudcrabs are the only foe you can survive, level your armor skill with them.

However, leveling armor skill doesn't really protect you... The best way to increase your armor is to get some armor perks.  If you aren't going to get the perks, then leveling the skill can be ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer! I didn't even know there was a hidden armor bonus ... I wore light armor boots because they had an useful enchantment. I'm wearing all four parts heavy armor now, my armor rating shows up at ~120. Does that mean I get that hidden armor bonus and my actual armor rating is >200?

Comment: Yes, the hidden armor is added to normal armor.  However, almost everywhere (including the calculation link), the hidden armor value is assumed to be 100.  Also, if you wore light armor boots, those would contribute the hidden armor rating - any piece that says "light armor" or "heavy armor" will contribute to hidden armor rating.  ~120 displayed armor rating is very low!  Work on your blacksmithing and upgrade your armor.